# how to find which word has maximum tfidf in a tfidf matrix for a single document?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, tf-idf

I'm curently using the following code. I have stored the tfidf matrix for all the documents, now I need the top n words for a particular document?
I am confused on how to get it?

This is the code I used till now. I need to find the words now from each document with highest tfidf

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import math
filenames=[]
corpus = []
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['article','similar','score'])
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, "r") as paper:
    corpus.append((file, paper.read()))
    filenames.append(file)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform([content for file, content in corpus])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index using `np.argmax` then use this to lookup the corresponding word in the `TfidfVectorizer._vocabulary`, as:

```
vocab_lookup = {v:k for k,v in tf.vocabulary_.items()}
[vocab_lookup[np.argmax(v)] for v in tfidf_matrix]
```

Comment: canyou be more specific?I'm new to python and I'm getting an error as      'TfidfVectorizer' object has no attribute '_vocabulary'

Comment: sorry it should be `vocabulary_`

Comment: also realised the key/values are the wrong order in the vocabulary_ you have to reverse them